# ASP.NET Assigning default user roles upon registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I assign default roles e.g. standard user upon user registration?

At the moment, I can manually assign roles by editing the table in SQL server but is there a way that a default role can assigned to all users?

I've tried using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734345/how-to-create-roles-and-add-users-to-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api) but it doesn't appear to work for projects using the ASP.NET Core Web Application (Visual Studio 2015).

```
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                // Send an email with this link
                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                //    $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? can you show us the code you written and the error message you received?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the default Asp .Net membership and role providers.

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "<role>");
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
_logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
 return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
 }
```

above code helps you to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this. I had the same problem. This worked for me.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string rolname = "User";                    
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, rolname);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
```